# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.internalMessagingAnnotationPostProcessor'

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm new at spring boot and my knowledge is so limited. I had an application that works with spring boot 2.1 and I want to use the last version of spring boot, which is 2.2.6. I did what should be done, changing other dependencies versions, activating bean definition overriding ..etc
But when I run the app I get this exception. any help will be very welcomed.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.integration.internalMessagingAnnotationPostProcessor':
>   BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration':
>   BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting
>   constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.security.access.method.MethodSecurityMetadataSource]:
>   Factory method 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: In the composition of
>   all global method configuration, no annotation support was actually
>   activated     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:240)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:722)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]    at
>   com.smartest.connectedwell.service.addtostore.AddToStoreApplication.main(AddToStoreApplication.java:17)
>   ~[classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration':
>   BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting
>   constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.security.access.method.MethodSecurityMetadataSource]:
>   Factory method 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: In the composition of
>   all global method configuration, no annotation support was actually
>   activated     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:409)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:109)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:251)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1141)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:506)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   ... 14 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting
>   constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.security.access.method.MethodSecurityMetadataSource]:
>   Factory method 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: In the composition of
>   all global method configuration, no annotation support was actually
>   activated     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:691)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:109)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:251)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1141)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:506)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   ... 35 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.security.access.method.MethodSecurityMetadataSource]:
>   Factory method 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: In the composition of
>   all global method configuration, no annotation support was actually
>   activated     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   ... 54 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.security.access.method.MethodSecurityMetadataSource]:
>   Factory method 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: In the composition of
>   all global method configuration, no annotation support was actually
>   activated     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   ... 64 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: In the composition
>   of all global method configuration, no annotation support was actually
>   activated     at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityMetadataSource(GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java:371)
>   ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   ... 65 common frames
>   omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In previous versions it was okay to have a null `MethodSecurityMetadataSource`, but now they added [this check](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.1.5.RELEASE/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java#L367) where if you don't have at least one method security metadata source enabled, they throw the exception that you are getting ("In the composition of all global method configuration, no annotation support was actually activated"). This happened to me when I updated from spring 5.0.7 to 5.1.5. Here is [the issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5341) where this change was discussed

To fix it, either enable one of the metadata sources in the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation properties, or, if like me, you are using some kind of `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`, make sure the method `customMethodSecurityMetadataSource` returns not-null

Answer (score -1):

You are right irt works with me after tried:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
```